# controlled Input with props

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, react-props, formik

So am doing a little project where i made a user profile page to show users profiles and where the admin can update their information. i wanted to do it with controlled inputs where in the same input it shows for exemple the name of the user and the admin can write something else in the same input.
but it didn't want to work and didn't know what i need to change exactly.

so let me explain what i did i have data that includes the user Name,
i get it with props.props.firstName
and it works fine
tried everything that i think can be done emptied the useState('') like this
removed the useEffect
removed the firstName state in the[] or the useEffect
and others but most of time it shows the firstName as undefined
sometimes it works but after a refresh it shows it again as undefined
[image]

```
const PersonalInformation = (props: any) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(props.props.firstName);

    useEffect(() => {
        setFirstName(props.props.firstName);
    }, [firstName]);

    console.log('state:', firstName, 'the prop:', props.props.firstName);


return (
        <Box>
            <NotificationBar open={open} setOpen={setOpen} message="notifMessage" type="info" />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" component="div">
                Personal Information
            </Typography>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    firstName: '',
                    lastName: '',
                    phone: '',
                }}
                onSubmit={() => {
                    // fn here
                }}
                validationSchema={changePersonalInfos}
            >
                {(formik) => (
                    <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                        <Grid container spacing={2}>
                            <Grid item xs={6}>
                                <InputField
                                    label="First Name"
                                    value={firstName}
                                    onChange={(e) => {
                                        formik.handleChange(e);
                                        setFirstName(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                />
                                <CustomError name="firstName" component="div" />
                            </Grid>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the useState or useEffect as formik should handle that.  maybe something like

```
// Helper styles for demo
import "./helper.css";
import { DisplayFormikState } from "./helper";

import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

interface Props{
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  phone: string
}
const PersonalInformation = ({firstName, lastName, phone}: Props) => (
  <div className="app">
    <h1>
    Personal Information
    </h1>

    <Formik
       initialValues={{
        firstName,
        lastName,
        phone
    }}
      onSubmit={values => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        firstName: Yup.string().required("Required"),
        lastName: Yup.string().required("Required"),
        phone: Yup.string().required("Required"),
      })}
    >
      {props => {
        const {
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
          dirty,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          handleReset
        } = props;
        return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="firstName" style={{ display: "block" }}>
              First
            </label>
            <input
              id="firstName"
              placeholder="Enter your first name"
              type="text"
              value={values.firstName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={
                errors.firstName && touched.firstName
                  ? "text-input error"
                  : "text-input"
              }
            />
             <label htmlFor="lastName" style={{ display: "block" }}>
              Last
            </label>
             <input
              id="lastName"
              placeholder="Enter your last name"
              type="text"
              value={values.lastName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={
                errors.lastName && touched.lastName
                  ? "text-input error"
                  : "text-input"
              }
            />
 <label htmlFor="phone" style={{ display: "block" }}>
              Last
            </label>
<input
              id="phone"
              placeholder="Enter your phone number"
              type="text"
              value={values.phone}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={
                errors.phone && touched.phone
                  ? "text-input error"
                  : "text-input"
              }
            />

            <button
              type="button"
              className="outline"
              onClick={handleReset}
              disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}
            >
              Reset
            </button>
            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              Submit
            </button>

            <DisplayFormikState {...props} />
          </form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: sadly, this is not what i need, i need for the input to still hold the possibility of writing in it .
if don't use the useState there are no other way to read the new text that i put